# createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error. reactJS to mongodb connection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I'm trying to connect React website to MongoDB, When I submit the username, email and password this message appears to me. although the first attempt success.

**Error Message**

```
xhr.js:187 POST http://localhost:8080/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
```

db.js

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()
const mongodb = require("mongodb")

mongodb.connect(process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, client) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  module.exports = client
  const app = require("./app")
  app.listen(process.env.PORT)
})
```

.env

```
CONNECTIONSTRING=mongodb+srv://username
PORT=8080
JWTSECRET=password
```

Can anyone help me with this, thank you In advance!

Comment: So are you using a post request from your frontend to send data to your backend, to save it in mongo ? Where is your backend Endpoint that is getting the request ?

Comment: Here Github link that contains the backend https://github.com/LearnWebCode/react-course/tree/master/backend-api